# Yet Another TCPClient Connection Issue

Tags: tcpclient

**Overview**
This issue has been killing me so badly lately. I'm trying to setup a connection over the net a server and client. Before I show my code I'd like to say that I've searched several threads on how to fix this issue but it is stumping me like crazy.

Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

To start things out here is a list of things I've tried:
  -Port Forwarding
  -Using local IPs and LAN IPs (i.e. 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.4, 10.0.0.150) These IPs will work and connect me to the server... my external IP will not.
  -Checked Firewall
  -Tried using different ports incase ISP was blocking specific ports (25567,28567, etc.)

Now for my Code...

Client Unity3D:

```
public string host = "Insert IP Here";
public int port = 25567;
public TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();
public void ConnectToServer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
            socket.SendTimeout = 100;
            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port));
            stream = socket.GetStream();
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            MasterCommunication MC = GameObject.Find("Main").GetComponent<MasterCommunication>();
            MC.setCommunicationPrams(socket, stream, reader, writer, true);
            socketReady = true;
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Connection timed out.");
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Server (Visual Studio):

```
        public static int port = 63292;
    private static TcpListener server;
    static void Main(string[] args) // Main Method
    {
        #region Initialization
        Console.WriteLine("...Server Initializing");
        clients = new List<ServerClient>();
        disconnectList = new List<ServerClient>();
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint IPEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            Console.WriteLine("...IPEP set to " + IPEP.AddressFamily);
            Console.WriteLine("...Port Set to " + port);
            server = new TcpListener(IPEP);
            server.Start();
            StartListening();
            Thread dataListener = new Thread(ListenForData);
            dataListener.Start();
            if (Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Database"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("...Database Found");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Database");
                Console.WriteLine("...Database Created");
            }
            Database.VerifyDatabase(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Database");
            Console.WriteLine("...Server has successfully started.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket error: " + e.Message);
        }
        #endregion


    }
```

Server (Second Half)

```
private static void StartListening() => server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);

    private static void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-New Connection");
            TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
            clients.Add(new ServerClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)));
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(clients.Last<ServerClient>().tcp.GetStream());
            writer.WriteLine(Encryption.Encrypt("Connected~Connected"));
            writer.Flush();
            StartListening();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            StartListening();
        }
    }
```

Halp T^T

Comment: A couple of network-configuration sanity-checks to try (from the same machine you are running your client program on):  (1) ping the server's IP address (or hostname, whichever you are specifying in your client program) -- if the ping packets don't get replied to, then you have a packet-routing or firewall issue.  (2) Run telnet with arguments specifying the IP-address/hostname and port your client wants to connect to (e.g. "telnet 1.2.3.4 25567") -- if telnet (which we know is not buggy) can't connect (it uses TCP also), then there is no way your program will be able to either.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for the swift reply. I pinged the IP the server is setup on and it pinged successfully, also I tried to run Telnet and it says "Could not open connection to the host, on port 25567: Connect Failed".

Comment: Okay, the message from telnet suggests that no server is listening on that port (or possibly that the tcp connection is being blocked by a firewall, although in that case telnet usually takes a while to error out instead of printing an error immediately)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it did take a about 10-15 seconds to error out. As I researched more on this issue provided with help of this thread I'd like to also bring to attention that when I check cmd 'netstat -abn' I see svchost.exe listening on port 25567 which is the port I've chosen for this project. I've used this port on prior projects that are not currently running. Is svchost.exe part of visual studio console projects? If not then I might have found the issue at hand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe